# Regex in python for special characters

Tags: python, regex

I need to find whether a given string is in this format or not.

```
anystr3ing1 : somesrritn3g
```

following is my code

```
prog = re.compile("([a-zA-Z0-9]\D)" + ":" + ([a-zA-Z0-9]\D)")

with open('data.txt','ru') as openfileobject:
  for line in openfileobject:
    if prog.match(line):
      print line
```

however its not giving any output

Comment: You have a syntax error. Is this the case in your actual code? Look at the first line, you are missing a " between `+` and  `([a-zA-Z0-9]\D)")` near the end of the line.

Comment: Also, this site will help to quickly test out regex: http://pythex.org

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the regex to:

```
[a-zA-Z0-9]+\s+:\s+[a-zA-Z0-9]+
```

Your problem is that you only matched one character from the class `[a-zA-Z0-9]`, followed by a non digit character, then ":" followed by `[a-zA-Z0-9]`.